# Recursively import data from nested csv files and create a ID column with month and year from file name

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have some air quality data from a bunch of rooms from a bunch of houses. I would like to recursively import data from the .csv files that are nested in folders that have the following file structure.  The problem I have is that whilst I can import them with lists without folder or files names (room names or date names), I can't work out how to extract the room name, month or year and attribute it to the list that is created so I can manipulate the data for plotting etc.

Can anyone please help extract the house number, room name, month and year from the file/folder names and use rbind to create a data.frame with **ID** columns that represents the house number, room, month and year?

This code works for one folder:

```
filenames <- list.files( pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE,recursive = T)
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
```

## To convert to data frame without IDs (loses which house and room the files belong to)

```
df <- dplyr::bind_rows(ldf)
df <- purrr::map_df(ldf, dplyr::bind_rows)
df <- purrr::map_df(ldf, ~.x)
```

File structure:

```
.
├── House 01
|   ├── Kitchen
|   |   ├──House 01 kitchen Apr 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 01 kitchen December 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 01 kitchen February 2018.csv
|   └── Living room
|   |   ├──House 01 living room Apr 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 01 living room December 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 01 living room February 2018.csv
├── House 02
|   ├── Kitchen
|   |   ├──House 02 kitchen Apr 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 02 kitchen December 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 02 kitchen February 2018.csv
|   └── Living room
|   |   ├──House 02 living room Apr 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 02 living room December 2019.csv
|   |   ├──House 02 living room February 2018.csv
```

Each csv file looks like this:

[image]

#### Edit: to include desired output.

The output I'd ideally like is a data.frame with columns:
Time, date, var1, var2, var2, houseNum, roomName

## This is what I've got based on AkselA's answer:

```
filenames <- list.files( pattern="*.csv", full.names=TRUE,recursive = T)
  
   >filenames
     [1] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom Apr 2019.csv"             
     [2] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom December 2018.csv"        
     [3] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom February 2019.csv"        
     [4] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom January 2018.csv"         
     [5] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom March 2019.csv"           
     [6] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom May 2019.csv"             
     [7] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom November 2018.csv"        
     [8] "./House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom October 2018.csv"         
     [9] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kit Apr 2019.csv"                 
    [10] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kit May 2019.csv"                 
    [11] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kitchen December 2018.csv"        
    [12] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kitchen February 2019.csv"        
    [13] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kitchen January 2019.csv"         
    [14] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kitchen March 2019.csv"           
    [15] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kitchen November 2018.csv"        
    [16] "./House 01 Kitchen/House 01 kitchen October 2018.csv"         
    [17] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 Liv Apr 2019.csv"             
    [18] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 Liv May 2019.csv"             
    [19] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 living room December 2018.csv"
    [20] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 living room February 2018.csv"
    [21] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 living room January 2018.csv" 
    [22] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 living room March 2018.csv"   
    [23] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 living room November 2018.csv"
    [24] "./House 01 Living room/House 01 living room October 2018.csv" 
    > 



ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv)
ldf<-lapply(ldf, function(y) { y["X"] <- NULL; y })

dn <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(dirname(filenames), "/")) #extracts month and year from
dn <- dn[,-(1:(ncol(dn)-2))]



colnames(dtf) <- c("House", "Room", "Month", "Year")
dtf$Date <- as.Date(paste(dtf$Month, dtf$Year, 1), "%b %Y %d")
cnamez<-c("Time","DevTime","pm2.5","Temp","RH","CO2","VOC.ppb","allpol")
ldf<-lapply(ldf, setNames, cnamez)



names(ldf)<-dn #Names the data frames 
AllData<-bind_rows(ldf, .id = "ID") #Binds them into data frames

library(stringr)
tmp<-str_split_fixed(AllData$ID, " ", 2) #Splits House number and room
tmp <- tmp[,-c(1,4)] #Removes excess
AllData$House<-tmp[,1] #Assigns house to be first column of tmp
AllData$Room<-tmp[,2]
AllData$ID<-NULL #Gets rid of ID column

head(AllData)
        Time          DevTime     pm2.5    Temp      RH   CO2 VOC.ppb    allpol House    Room
1 1554073200 01/04/2019 00:00  7.320007 18.7700 48.9200 452.0     125  7.320007    01 Bedroom
2 1554073500 01/04/2019 00:05  7.550003 18.7595 48.9190 451.0     125  7.550003    01 Bedroom
3 1554073800 01/04/2019 00:10  8.240021 18.7270 48.9600 453.0     126  8.382878    01 Bedroom
4 1554074100 01/04/2019 00:15 14.450012 18.7205 48.9815 452.5     126 14.592871    01 Bedroom
5 1554074400 01/04/2019 00:20 19.740020 18.7050 48.9930 463.0     129 20.311450    01 Bedroom
6 1554074700 01/04/2019 00:25 17.210022 18.6995 48.9875 468.0     130 17.924307    01 Bedroom
```

Comment: Presumable if you run your `list.files()` command in the directory that houses all the House directories, you get all the CSVs imported as data frames in a list, and the names of the list are the full file paths. If you then run `dplyr::bind_rows` or `data.table::rbindlist`, you can combine them into one data frame with an `ID` column with the full file path. So then then the only issue is how to extract the information in the file path (house number, room name and number, date) into their own columns, correct?...

Comment: ...To do that, the only input that really matters is the file path as a string (as it is in the list names / ID column), and the output you want. Can you please share both of those? I don't think the other columns matter (and the image you share of them isn't really useful). The file structure lets me guess what the file path strings look like, but it would be much nicer to copy/paste than to guess. And it would be really nice to have the sample output you want. e.g., your file structure has files named "bedroom" in a folder named "kitchen", what do you want the new columns to be?

Comment: You are aware of  `dplyr::bind_rows(ldf, .id="House_Room")` this syntax, right?

Comment: @M-M how does the list know about House_Room? After I ran that code, it has a column House_Room with values 1 to 8 but that's not representative of either the house number or the room number. It must be the file ID.

Comment: See the help page `?bind_rows`. *"When a list of data frames is supplied, the labels are taken from the names of the list. If no names are found a numeric sequence is used instead."* If, for some reason, your list isn't named, do `names(ldf) = filenames)` before using `bind_rows` with the `.id` argument specified.

Comment: @HCAI I meant to suggest combining bind_rows with what Gregor suggested. Get the full directory as name and then use .id to have it as a column.

Comment: @Gregor and M-M thank you both. It's looking good. I'm working through AkselA's answer below to see if I can adapt it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the sharepoint link you provided I made a compact [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which captures most of the irregularities in the full data set. The main problem was empty data.frames, and they weren't hard to find, even though not all of them had `(no data)` in the file name. While it's easy enough to just discard the empty data.frames, I opted to keep them by filling in a single row of `NA`s. If these rows turns out to be a nuisance they're easy enough to remove later on.
I've tried this on the full data set, and it works fine.

#### Sample data

```
# set.seed(2)
# filenames <- list.files("Foobot", recursive=TRUE, full.names=TRUE)
# filenames[sample(length(filenames), 5)][c(1, 4, 5)]
# ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.csv, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
# s <- sapply(ldf, nrow) != 0
# ldf[s] <- lapply(ldf[s], function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), sample(2:3)),])
# ldf <- lapply(ldf, "rownames<-", NULL)

filenames <- c(
  "Foobot/House 04 foobot data/House 04 bedroom/House 04 bed Mar 2019.csv",
  "Foobot/House 03 foobot data/House 03 Living room/House 03 Liv May 2019.csv",
  "Foobot/House 18 foobot data/House 18 living room/House 18 liv Feb 2019.csv")

ldf <- list(structure(list(time..s.=logical(0), Device.Local.Time=logical(0),
  pm..ugm3.=logical(0), tmp..C.=logical(0), hum..pc.=logical(0),
  co2..ppm.=logical(0), voc..ppb.=logical(0), allpollu....=logical(0),
  X=logical(0)), class="data.frame", row.names=integer(0)),
  structure(list(time..s.=c(1557342000L, 1556863500L),
  Device.Local.Time=c("08/05/2019 20:00", "03/05/2019 07:05"),
  pm..ugm3.=c(18.660004, 43.5), tmp..C.=c(17.73, 17.5), hum..pc.=c(55.947,
  50.739), co2..ppm.=c(1187, 1003), voc..ppb.=c(328, 277),
  allpollu....=c(45.99334, 59.928574)), row.names=c(NA, -2L),
  class="data.frame"), structure(list(time..s.=c(1549291500L, 1550995200L,
  1550111100L), Device.Local.Time=c("04/02/2019 14:45", "24/02/2019 08:00",
  "14/02/2019 02:25"), pm..ugm3.=c(13.76001, 8.4700165, 11), tmp..C.=c(21.407,
  16.972, 20.918), hum..pc.=c(48.643997, 55.678, 52.008), co2..ppm.=c(643, 910,
  738), voc..ppb.=c(178, 251.5, 204.5), allpollu....=c(21.331438, 26.541447,
  22.357143), X=c(NA, NA, NA)), row.names=c(NA, -3L), class="data.frame"))
```

#### Processing

```
# One of the data.frames have zero rows
sapply(ldf, dim)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    2    3
# [2,]    9    8    9

# Forcing all the data.frames to have at least one row results in
# padding with NAs for those that have less
ldf <- lapply(ldf, 
  function(x) data.frame(
    lapply(x, "length<-", max(c(1, nrow(x)))),
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE))

# Extract metadata from the directory names
dn <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(dirname(filenames), "/"))
dn <- dn[,-(1:(ncol(dn)-2))]
dn[,1] <- sub("^(House [0-9]+) .*", "\\1", dn[,1])
dn[,2] <- tolower(sub("^House [0-9]+ ", "", dn[,2]))

# Extract metadata from the base names
bn <- strsplit(sub("\\.csv$", "", basename(filenames)), " ")
bn <- t(sapply(bn, tail, 2))

# Combine and create Date column
dtf <- data.frame(dn, bn, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(dtf) <- c("House", "Room", "Month", "Year")
dtf$Date <- as.Date(paste(dtf$Month, dtf$Year, 1), "%b %Y %d")

# Multi-argument intersection function
intsect <- function(x) {
    Reduce(function(x, y) unique(y[match(x, y, 0L)]), x)
}

# Create vectors of valid column names
ldf.cn <- intsect(lapply(ldf, colnames))
dtf.cn <- colnames(dtf)

# Bind metadata and sensor data
ldf.cbind <- mapply(function(dtf, ldf) {
    d <- cbind(c(dtf), ldf, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
    d <- d[, c("House", "Room", "Date", ldf.cn)]
    d
}, split(dtf, 1:nrow(dtf)), ldf, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)

# Bind list of data.frames to one tall data.frame
ldf.rbind <- do.call(rbind, ldf.cbind)

# Convert to date-time
ldf.rbind$Device.Local.Time <- as.POSIXct(
  ldf.rbind$Device.Local.Time, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")

# Control that all the column classes make sense
sapply(ldf.rbind[1,], function(x) class(x)[1])
#             House              Room              Date          time..s. 
#       "character"       "character"            "Date"         "integer" 
# Device.Local.Time         pm..ugm3.           tmp..C.          hum..pc. 
#         "POSIXct"         "numeric"         "numeric"         "numeric" 
#         co2..ppm.         voc..ppb.      allpollu.... 
#         "numeric"         "numeric"         "numeric"

# Inspect subset of final data.frame
ldf.rbind[sample(nrow(ldf.rbind), 3),]
#        House        Room       Date   time..s.   Device.Local.Time
# 1   House 04     bedroom 2019-03-01         NA                <NA>
# 3.3 House 18 living room 2019-02-01 1550111100 2019-02-14 02:25:00
# 2.2 House 03 living room 2019-05-01 1556863500 2019-05-03 07:05:00
#     pm..ugm3. tmp..C. hum..pc. co2..ppm. voc..ppb. allpollu....
# 1          NA      NA       NA        NA        NA           NA
# 3.3      11.0  20.918   52.008       738     204.5     22.35714
# 2.2      43.5  17.500   50.739      1003     277.0     59.92857
```

Comment: Thank you, this is looking nice. There are some odd named files but I'll manually fix them. Can I ask how I use dtf to apply the names to the list I've made please?

Comment: @HCAI: I added a suggestion. You can of course change the format however you want.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to bind the metadata in dtf to my list of imported data in ldf. your ldf is another list of names. Sorry for the odd question: how do I do it?

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you wanted to bind them. How do you want to do it? By column and just repeat the values the required number of rows?

Comment: I'm less familiar with lists but as a dataframe the air quality data for each house ideally would be stacked in long format with a unique identifier for each house and room. Does that make sense? Thank you again for introducing me to how flexible lists are.

Comment: @HCAI: If you do `do.call(rbind, ldf.bind)`, does that give you what you want?

Comment: Thank you for the update. I think there's something different with my data. Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 1, 0 . But ldf has 24 elements for me and dtf has 24 obs. of 5 variables. What am I missing?

Comment: @HCAI: Where does the error occur? Have you stepped through the code and checked that everything looks OK up to that point?

Comment: It's when we try to bind the meta data using mapply. Everything is ok up to that point plus or minus some minor tweaks because my data is clearly not as nice as suggestd. I've run: head(cbind(c(dtf), ldf, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)) and get: In cbind(c(dtf), ldf, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) :
  number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Comment: @HCAI: Does it happen for every element in the list, or just for some? If you post a subset of the list that throws the error, I could have a go. Try making the data as small and simple as you can, while it's still giving error.

Comment: It happens with just 1 file unfortunately. Here's a non-permanent link to the data structure: https://leeds365-my.sharepoint.com/:f:/g/personal/cenmk_leeds_ac_uk/EphSMAh3hgFAtlhhdPzV3oIB7tHdwglKu4tHBHijHSZWRA?e=jjOALi . I bet you will say it's because my real data or structure is not well represented by my example above so I apologise beforehand but I cannot see why. Any further help thought would be much appreciated.

Comment: @HCAI: Which one's the naughty one?

Comment: I've just put my code into an edit so you can see any little tweaks based on your code. I'm in House 01 footbot data and straight away is giving difficulty. Do you get the same?

Comment: @HCAI: I've updated the answer. Finding the problem wasn't too hard, you just have to run the code with small subsets of the data until it crashes, and then inspect the data that caused it. In this case the main problem was some empty data.frames.

Comment: thank you so much for routing through this! I'd like to offer you a bounty when the system allows me to. On a side-note, it does seem like bringing in data with filenames is complicated for the uninitiated. Is there something could have been done when saving the files from the sensor to start with to simplify this process?

Comment: This sort of complexity is pretty much par for the course when it comes to passing data between different systems. You can easily end up with something much more complicated if the data is more complicated/unstructured/variable. 1/3

Comment: One common approach when you want to include metadata with a file format that doesn't support it is the use of [sidecar files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidecar_file). In this case you could have the csv. files as is, but add a .txt file with the same name that holds the metadata in a simple, easy to read format. 2/3

Comment: What I'd probably prefer is to add the metadata to the .csv files as a sort of header. Say you add a line to the top of the .csv file: Date, House, Room, and let the csv data below stay unmodified. In R you could then use `read.csv()` with the `skip=1` argument to read the sensor data, and `read.csv()` with the `nrows=1` argument to read the metadata. You'd still have to do a similar, but slightly simpler, `mapply()` call to join them. One disadvantage of this of course is that something like Excel could have trouble reading these files. There's always tradeoffs. 3/3

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you close. Import the CSVs with readr's `read_csv` in purrr's `map`. Set the list names using `paths`, then bind the dataframes using argument `.id = "path"` to include a column with the list element names. Separate the paths by "/" with tidyr's `separate`. Remove redundant strings from the file names using stringr's `str_remove` and the other variables as patterns. Finally, separate what's left of the file names with another call to separate:

```r
library(tidyverse)

paths <- list.files(pattern = "csv$", recursive = T)

map(paths, read_csv) %>% 
    set_names(paths) %>% 
    bind_rows(.id = "path") %>% 
    separate(path, c("house", "room", "file"), "/") %>% 
    mutate(file = file %>%
               str_remove(regex(house, T)) %>%
               str_remove(regex(room, T)) %>% 
               str_remove("\\.csv") %>% 
               str_trim,
           house = parse_number(house)
           ) %>% 
    separate(file, c("month", "year"), convert = T)
```

Which returns the following, using some synthetic data:

```r
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  house room        month    year time   var1  var2  var3 
  <dbl> <chr>       <chr>   <int> <drtn> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 Kitchen     Apr      2019 02:00  blah  bleh  bluh 
2     1 Living room June     2018 12:00  blah  bleh  bluh 
3     2 Kitchen     July     2019 08:00  blah  bleh  bluh 
4     2 Living room January  2016 16:00  blah  bleh  bluh
```

Comment: Wow, this look good too, thank you. I'm trying to run line by line because it produces warnings in the first map function. Warning: 7639 parsing failures.
row # A tibble: 5 x 5 col     row col   expected  actual    file                                  expected   <int> <chr> <chr>     <chr>     <chr>                                 actual 1     1 NA    8 columns 9 columns './House 01 bedroom October 2018.csv' . This must be due to what the file looks like right? (sorry to ask this type of question here).

Comment: @HCAI it's because I included the argument `col_types = "cccc"`, so `read_csv` expects four character variables. I'll remove it from the code so you can try again and let `read_csv` guess the class.

Comment: @HCAI I made some modifications to keep things flexible. That includes removing the part that created the datetime. The problem is that you `time` variable wouldn't work as is. I think the code will work now without throwing any errors.

Comment: thanks again. I'm going through line by line and getting stuck on separate. I've gone into House 1 bedroom and left 1 file in the directory: > paths
[1] "House 01 bedroom Apr 2019.csv".  There's no "/" in the paths entry though. Any thoughts?

Comment: @HCAI there are two calls to `separate`: The first deals with the paths with `/`, and the second deals with the file name. For it to work you need the complete path from the working directory,  e.g. `House 01/Kitchen/House 01 kitchen Apr 2019.csv`, and your working directory should be whatever folder the House XX folders are in.

Comment: Ahh, I see yes. looking at the path, it's actually a bit messier: paths
  [1] "House 01 foobot data/House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom Apr 2019.csv"

Comment: Ahh, I see yes. looking at the path, it's actually a bit messier: paths
  [1] "House 01 foobot data/House 01 Bedroom/House 01 bedroom Apr 2019.csv" so it's still a bit stuck with this even though I do like the idea of tidyverse.